# Apple Pay on React Native?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, applepay, applepayjs

I want to integrate Apple Pay into my React Native app and i've tried both react-native-payments and expo-payments-stripe but none of them work properly. React-native-payments doesn't even seem to be maintained anymore.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into [tipsi-stripe](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe) as they do have an Apple Pay implementation.

Comment: Alright I will, thanks! @taintedzodiac